# sample spring data neo4j project downloaded from spring.io is throwing maven jar error

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I have downloaded the spring data neo4j rest code from the following location

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-neo4j-data-rest/

when I am running maven command to package I am getting following error.

```
    [INFO]                                                                         
   [INFO]   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Building gs-accessing-neo4j-data-rest 0.1.0
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-dsl-2.0.1.pom
   [WARNING] The POM for org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
   Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/2.0.1/neo4j-cypher-dsl-2.0.1.jar
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time: 6.861 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-04T03:53:47-04:00
   [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/60M
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gs-accessing-neo4j-data-rest:  Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework:gs-accessing-neo4j-data-rest:jar:0.1.0: Could not find artifact org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher-dsl:jar:2.0.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I don't know how to resolve this. can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following section to main pom.xml so that Maven will be able to find and download missing artifact(s):

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j</id>
        <name>Neo4j</name>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```